# AWS - Locking down ports

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

This has probably been answered elsewhere but I can't seem to find it!

I have a number of AWS EC2 instances that I am using as part of a project being built and I am now looking into securing the setup a bit. I want to lock down access to some of the ports.

For example I want to have one of the instances act as a database server (hosting mysql). I want this to be closed to public access but open to access from my other EC2 instances on their private IP's.

I also use the AWS auto-scaler to add/remove instances as required and need these to be able to access the DB server without having to manually add its IP to a list.

Similarly if possible I want to lock down some instances so that they can only accept traffic from an AWS Load Balancer. So port 80 is open on the instance but only for traffic coming from the Load Balancer.

I've looked at specifying the IP's using CIDR notation but can't seem to get it working. From the look of the private IP's being assigned to my instances the first two octets remain the same and the last two vary. But opening it to all instances with the same first two octets doesn't seem that secure either?!

Thanks

Comment: use security groups, not CIDR.

Comment: As @tedder42 mentions... when creating a rule in a security group to allow traffic, you can allow traffic from an IP address or block, *or* from machines in another security group, by specifying the sg-xxxxxxxx security group identifier instead of an IP address.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want to do is all pretty standard stuff, and is extensively documented in the AWS VPC documentation for Virtual Private Clouds. If your EC2 instances are not running in a VPC, they should be.

The link below should help, it seems to be your scenario:

> **Scenario 2: VPC with Public and Private Subnets (NAT)**
>
> The configuration for this scenario includes a VPC with a public
>   subnet and private subnet, and a network address translation (NAT)
>   instance in the public subnet. A NAT instance enables instances in the
>   private subnet to initiate outbound traffic to the Internet. *We
>   recommend this scenario if you want to run a public-facing web
>   application, while maintaining back-end servers that aren't publicly
>   accessible*. A common example is a multi-tier website, with the web
>   servers in a public subnet and the database servers in a private
>   subnet. You can set up security and routing so that the web servers
>   can communicate with the database servers.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/UserGuide/VPC_Scenario2.html